# How to copy a file system to a smaller device

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, raspberry-pi, sd-card

As I used it to copy a 32 GB SD card (13 GiB used) to a 16 GB SD card, i share with you the process bellow (it was for a raspberry pi) :
I have lost some times with /dev/loop0...

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have 2 unmounted partitions /dev/mmcblk0p1 (boot fat16, 100 MiB) and /dev/mmcblk0p2 (ext4, ~31,9 GB) on the first SD card to copy.

1. copy partitions to files :

   ```
   sudo dd bs=1M if=/dev/mmcblk0p1 of=/home/pi/file_part1 status=progress
   sudo dd bs=1M if=/dev/mmcblk0p2 of=/home/pi/file_part2 status=progress
   ```
2. resize partition

   The first partition is boot, no need to resize
   Check partition ext4 with `e2fsck` (it must be done before `resize2fs`):

   ```
   sudo e2fsck /home/pi/file_part2 
   sudo resize2fs /home/pi/file_part2 14G
   ```

   I choose 14G cause my filesystem used 13GiB, if your filesystem use less choose a smaller number).

   Verify that the size of the file `file_part2` is now 14 GiB (and not 32 GB)

   **Caution** with *gibibytes* (2^30) and *gigabytes* (10^9), it can make big differences:

   If you have for example a 15 GiB filesystem (15 * 2^30 bytes = 16 492 674 416 640 bytes) for a "16 GB" SD card (16 000 000 000 bytes) SD card, it won't fit...
3. recreate partition table on the second SD card

   I let you recreate the partition table with `fdisk` or other tools on the second SD card, for example with the manual of installation of `archlinux` on the raspberry pi 4: https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-4

   **note**: you can also cheat with `dd` in copying the first 200M of `/dev/mmcblk0` of the first SD card to the second SD card to recreate the partition table (and boot partition by the way).
4. copy files to partitions of the second SD card (16 GB)

   ```
   sudo dd bs=1M if=/home/pi/file_part1 of=/dev/mmcblk0p1 status=progress
   sudo dd bs=1M if=/home/pi/file_part2 of=/dev/mmcblk0p2 status=progress
   ```
5. mount `/dev/mmcblk0p2` to modify files (like `/etc/fstab`) before boot the new SD card (on your raspberry pi)